# Why won't my images scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, onmouseover

Here's my site:

violetoeuvre.com

I'd like to program the home image to change when it's scrolled over.

Here's my javascript:

```
<!-- Photo __________________________________________-->

    <div id="home_photo">

        <img id="home_photo" src="images/photo/1.jpg" />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var myimages=[
                "images/photo/1.jpg",
                "images/photo/2.jpg",
                "images/photo/3.jpg",
                "images/photo/4.jpg",
                "images/photo/5.jpg",
                "images/photo/6.jpg",
                "images/photo/7.jpg",
                "images/photo/8.jpg",
                "images/photo/9.jpg",
                "images/photo/10.jpg",
                "images/photo/12.jpg",
                "images/photo/13.jpg",
                "images/photo/14.jpg",
                "images/photo/15.jpg",
                "images/photo/16.jpg",
                "images/photo/18.jpg",
                "images/photo/19.jpg",
                "images/photo/20.jpg",
                "images/photo/21.jpg",
                "images/photo/22.jpg",
                "images/photo/23.jpg",
                ]
                var slideshow=document.getElementById("slideshow")
                var nextslideindex=0
                function rotateimage(e){
                var evt=window.event || e
                var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta
                nextslideindex=(delta<=-120)? nextslideindex+1 : nextslideindex-1
                nextslideindex=(nextslideindex<0)? myimages.length-1 : (nextslideindex>myimages.length-1)? 0 : nextslideindex
                slideshow.src=myimages[nextslideindex]
                if (evt.preventDefault)
                evt.preventDefault()
                else
                return false
                }
                var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"

                if (slideshow.attachEvent)
                slideshow.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, rotateimage)
                else if (slideshow.addEventListener)
                slideshow.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, rotateimage, false)
                </script>
    </div>
```

As you see, I've got 23 images that should change when scrolled over. I can't find what's wrong.

Maybe something in my divs is messed up? Or I'm misusing the id elements?

Thank you!

Comment: You _don't_ have 23 images. Some of the IDs are missing from the array.

Comment: The `div` has the same ID as the `img` inside it. Also, I can't see any element with the ID `slideshow`. Fix that. Maybe it'll work then?

Comment: Since it seems your code throws a `TypeError`, I assume Revent is correct in noting that you didn't debug your code?

Comment: Also note jQuery normalises the [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event (I admit, it's not exactly the same event as `mousewheel`) , as well as `addEventListener`. Perhaps you might like it, especially since you might want to add animations later?

Comment: I reloaded the images and it's now working. I don't have great knowledge of javascript. So, I just used this code:
http://scrollimage.blogspot.com/
the demo is from
http://full-tricks.blogspot.com/2011/07/change-image-just-with-scroll.html
I'm not sure why it works. I agree it's confusing that the seemingly arbitrary element "slideshow" makes it work.
I fixed my site now...
violetoeuvre.com

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The code sample indicates the `img` should have the ID `slideshow`, while you gave it the ID `home_photo`.

Comment: If you're just doing photos, check out <a href="http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/">Nivo Slider</a>. Also please accept my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Hm, ok, I see. thanks everyone! whoa, nivo slider looks amazing. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all you are setting your slideshow variable to an element that doesn't exist. Where is the "slideshow" element? And Jan is right, ID's must be unique.

I recommend getting [Firebug for FireFox](https://getfirebug.com/downloads) if you don't already have it, it's very useful for debugging javascript.

Comment: The Chrome developer console (built-in) is great as well.